# How to split sphinx index without reindexing?

Tags: sphinx

I have one real-time index. I use attributes and full-text fields. I need to split index in several indexes for load balancing. I can reindex original data, but retrieving original data from storage is quite expensive. Is it possible to split index without reindexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK no, this is not possible. (at least there are no provided utilities, would have to write your own)